# Conditional Statement to compare line of a text file to each line of another file

Tags: python, nested, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to compare multiple lists in Python. The idea is that we have multiple lists and are comparing each item in each list to a list of aggregated unique values. We then create an excel sheet where we would show each list side by side and any values missing from a particular list would show as PLACEHOLDER in that cell.

(I had a hard time explaining, but if you don't understand after reading please ask questions and I'll adjust the explanation accordingly )

```
filecount = 0
for file in files:
    filecount += 1
    with open(file) as file_object:
        row = 0
        for line in agg_Names:
            #if line match, output to row
            print (file_object)
            if line in file_object.readlines():
                worksheet.write(row, filecount, line)
                row += 1
                print ("found match")
```

The last if statement isn't right. It's supposed to compare each item in agg_Names to the current list and output the value. Currently, I'm only getting matches on the first row.

Comment: change "if line in file_object.readlines():" to "for fline in file_object.readlines(): if line == fline:" the current code only does a match once, thats the reason you are getting only first row.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting only a single line is because `readlines()` returns all the lines of the file as a list and your comparison happens only once.

So, after your first iteration, `file_object.readlines()` would be empty because the buffer (`file_object`) is empty.

You can modify your code to this,

```
filecount = 0
for file in files:
    filecount += 1
    with open(file) as file_object:
        file_lines = file_object.readlines()
    row = 0
    for line in agg_Names:
        #if line match, output to row
        if line in file_lines:
            worksheet.write(row, filecount, line)
            row += 1
            print ("found match")
```

Hope this helps.